# CNN: Splitting Train, Test, and Validation and saving training progress

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am writing code for the following problem:

- I have a fruit dataset containing train and test directories. In both these directories, contain the 6 classes (fresh/rotten apples, fresh/rotten oranges, fresh/rotten bananas).
- I am using transfer learning on MobileNetV2 model

I am trying to get my data splits set up properly, but am confused on how to...

1. Get train, validation, and test splits set-up
2. How to check that they are indeed set up properly (no sort of overlaps of data for example)
3. How do I save progress through training. (Example: I run my script that trains for 10 epochs. How do I make sure that the training continues from where I left off when I run my script again for x epochs.)

My code so far:

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input, validation_split=0.20).flow_from_directory(
    train_path, target_size=(im_height, im_width), batch_size=batch_size)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(
    test_path, target_size=(im_height, im_width), batch_size=batch_size)

mobv2 = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2()

x = mobv2.layers[-2].output
output_layer = Dense(units=6, activation='softmax')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=mobv2.input, outputs=output_layer)
for layer in model.layers[:-25]:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.0001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy']
              )
```

Here is my fit, but haven't completed it yet, as I'm not sure what to include for validation and test....

```
model.fit(train_batches, steps_per_epoch=4, )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see code below

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input, validation_split=0.20).flow_from_directory(
    train_path, target_size=(im_height, im_width), batch_size=batch_size,
     subset='training)
valid_batches=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input, validation_split=0.20).flow_from_directory(
    train_path, target_size=(im_height, im_width), batch_size=batch_size,
     subset='validation')
epochs = 15 # set the number of epochs to run
history=model.fit(train_batches,  epochs=epochs, verbose=1, 
                validation_data=valid_batches, verbose=1)'
```

to get better results I also recommend you consider using an adjustable learning
rate using the Keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/) Set it up to monitor validation loss . Use the code below:

```
rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5,
                                            patience=10, verbose=1)
```

I also recommend you use the Keras callback EarlyStopping. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/) Use the code below

```
es=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=3, verbose=1,    
                                  restore_best_weights=True)
```

Now in model.fit include

```
callbacks=[rlronp, es]
```

Comment: I see in the model.fit() you declare verbose=1 twice. Is it necessary to do this, or can you just declare it once?@Gerry

Comment: No it was just a typo, declare it once.